# Search filters not functioning on first attempt

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a search filter based on flags of different colors.
If I will search based on color it is showing result but when I will select white color flag it is showing entire data in my database table. But If I choose any other color apart from white color for the first time it will show result. And if I choose white color flag second time,then it gives the correct result. What might be the reason. I need help

//filter on flag_color

```
if($this->input->get('flg')){
        $arr_flag   =   explode('-', $this->input->get('flg'));
        $str_flag   =   implode(',',$arr_flag);
        if(6    ==  $str_flag){
            $str_flag   =   0;
        }
        $str_condition  .=  'AND t.sender_flag_color_id IN('.$str_flag.')';
} 

array(
    '0'=>array(
                'color'=>'White',
                'path'=>'whiteflag.png'),
    '1'=> array(
                'color'=>'Blue',
                'path'=>'blueflag.png'),
    '2'=>array(
                'color'=>'Green',
                'path'=>'greenflag.png'),
    '3'=>array(
                'color'=>'Yellow',
                'path'=>'yellowflag.png'),
    '4'=>array(
                'color'=>'Red',
                'path'=>'redflag.png') ,
    '5'=>array(
                'color'=>'Orange',
                'path'=>'orangeflag.png')
);
```

view

```
<?php
    $arr_params     =   $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
    $arr_flag       =   array();
    if(isset($arr_params['flg']))
    { ?>



        <input type="hidden" id="flag_in_url" name="flag_in_url" value="yes" />
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <!-- id="webmenu1" -->
<select class="flag_color" onchange="urgency_select('flag_color')" name="header_flag" id="webmenuflag1">
<?php
    $arr_params     =   $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
    $arr_flag       =   array();
    $int_flag_url   =   '';
    if(isset($arr_params['flg']))
    {
        $int_flag_url   =   $arr_params['flg'];
    }

    if(isset($arr_flag_color))
    {
        foreach($arr_flag_color as $key=>$flag_color)
        { 
            if($int_flag_url    ==  $key)
            {
                $flag_selected  =   'selected';
            }
            else
            {
                $flag_selected  =   '';
            }
            ?>
            <option <?php echo $flag_selected;?> value="<?php echo $key;?>" data-image="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $flag_color['path'];?>"></option>
            <?php 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

js: urgency_select

```
var flag_color_id   =   '';
        if(select_option    ==  'flag_color' || $( "#flag_in_url" ).val()   ==  'yes')
        {
            if($( ".flag_color" ).val() != undefined)
            {
                var flag_color_id   =   $( ".flag_color" ).val();
                if(flag_color_id    ==  0)
                    flag_color_id   =   6;
                search_url  +=  'flg/'+flag_color_id+'/';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Question is not clear. can you please explain more?

Comment: I have a filter option in my project. Filter is based on flags of different colors. Suppose if I select white color flag , it will display all details with different flag color . But this is not in case of other colors. Suppose if I select any color flag apart from white color first time it gives correct result. Now if I am selecting white color next time , then it gives me correct result. Problem is issue with white color flag filter on first time selection

Comment: what might be the reason for that situation to happen

Comment: That you have explained above. :-) problem is that i am not able to something from your code samples. What do you get in to variables after explode and implode. If you implode into a comma separated value how is it possible to check 6 == $ var. Also what is 6 doing here

Comment: Give me few seconds. I will update the codes

Comment: Without knowing what values are getting as ur input I cant say anything..but just noticed that the key associated with white is zero. May be it is causing issue. Do you allow multiselect?

Comment: No no mutliselect option is not there.

Comment: what value you get in `$arr_flag   =   explode('-', $this->input->get('flg'));
        $str_flag   =   implode(',',$arr_flag);` as your js it should be an integer. i assume $arr_flag_color is the one u defined above

Comment: There I am getting value 6

Comment: Confused. if you are getting an integer why are imploding it.? any reason? can you please export your db dumb including data, and paste in https://gist.github.com/ and any other files that can help me understand what your code does? In simple terms all that you need to do is 1) list colors as dropdown. 2) on selection of a color fetch the color id and get its data from database. ie all right? share what have you done so far. It is hard to guess always :-).  what is the initial part of `$str_condition`

Comment: Thank you VipindasKS . I got the answer. Its because conflict with the value of white color flag... In the model I changed the code if($int_flag_url    ==  $key)
            {
                $flag_selected  =   'selected';
            } to if($int_flag_url    == 0 || $int_flag_url    ==  $key)
            {
                $flag_selected  =   'selected';
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because conflict with the value of white color flag...
 In the view I changed the code

```
if($int_flag_url == $key)
 { 
    $flag_selected = 'selected'; 
 }
```

to

```
if($int_flag_url == 0 || $int_flag_url == $key) 
{ 
    $flag_selected = 'selected'; 
}
```